# Print $\sigma$ for Shiny, not $$\sigma$$

Tags: r, shiny

I want print the TeX script `$\simga$` and not `$$\sigma$$`. But the following code is not functional when I use `$\simga$` instead of `$$\sigma$$`.

In the following code, please execute two times, first use `$\simga$` and secondly use  `$$\sigma$$`.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a  TeX
        mainPanel(
            shiny::uiOutput("formula")
        )
    )
)

# Define server  
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$formula <- renderUI({

        # s<-"$\\sigma$" This is not functional, why???????

        s<-"$$\\sigma$$"
        withMathJax(s)        

    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output is the followings;
[image]

---

Edit for the answer

Exactly works, Thank you @Henryk Gerlach !

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a  TeX
        mainPanel(
            shiny::uiOutput("formula")
        )
    )
)

# Define server  
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$formula <- renderUI({

        # s<-"$\\sigma$" This is not functional, why???????

        s<-'\\( \\sigma \\) \\( \\sigma \\) \\( \\sigma \\)'
        withMathJax(s)        

    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Since single-dollars do not start in new line, it is exactly, single-dollars. Thank you @Henryk Gerlach,... great.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the configured [delimiter](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#tex-and-latex-math-delimiters), by default

```
s<-'\\( \\sigma \\)'
```

should work.